# GUI (view) start up is messed up

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I previously had help with creating the GUI (Thank you @Hovercraft Full Of Eels).

Initially my GUI looked like this when start up.
[image]

and when you run the program, it looks like this.
[image]

Now after I edited it, it's start up looks like this.(Messed up)
[image]

and then when you run the program it looks like this.
[image]

Basically the startup screen looks messed up but when you press the button, it reverts back to normal but the background looks messed up.

Here is how the code looks like

The Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Envrionment Stimulation");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(input.getGui());    //input is a class that takes the size of the grid and uses it to call the Layout class
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the Layout class that input calls after getting the inputs for it

```
public class Layout extends JPanel {

    private static final int WIDTH = 75;
    private static final int SPACING = 15;
    private final GridControls btnAndTxt;
    private final Grid map;

    public Layout(Earth earth, int xCount, int yCount) {

        //Making our borders
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(SPACING, SPACING, SPACING,SPACING));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(SPACING, SPACING));

        //The Map
        map = new Grid(WIDTH, xCount, yCount);

        //Buttons and Text
        btnAndTxt = new GridControls(map, earth);

        //Adding the JPanels.
        add(btnAndTxt, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Next will be the Grid which is how our GUI will be initialized

```
public class Grid extends JPanel {

    private final JLabel[][] label;
    private final int xCount, yCount;

    public Grid(int width, int xCount, int yCount) {
        this.xCount = xCount;
        this.yCount = yCount;

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(yCount, xCount, 1, 1));
        label = new JLabel[yCount][xCount];

        for (int y = 0; y < yCount; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < xCount; x++) {
                label[y][x] = new JLabel(".", SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label[y][x].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
                label[y][x].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                label[y][x].setOpaque(true);
                label[y][x].setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                add(label[y][x]);
            }
    }

    public void updateGrid(Mappable[][] map) {
        for (int y = 0; y < yCount; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < xCount; x++) {
                label[y][x].setText(map[y][x] == null ? "." : map[y][x].toString());
            }
    }

    public int getY() {
        return yCount;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return xCount;
    }
}
```

For the GridControl class, it extends Jpanel. I used add() method for Button and Text (Button, Text, Button) order but I did not use any layout managers. Could this be the problem? The Initial GUI did not utilize layout manager for the Buttons and Text panel as well. (Layout class stayed the same)

*Edit1: *Updated how grid looks like*

I had getX() and getY() method while the class was extending JPanel. It override the methods that's why it was causing errors on the GUI.

Comment: In your previous question, I posted with my answer, a small self-contained runnable GUI program that demonstrated the points I was trying to make in my answer, a [mcve]. You should do the same thing with this question: create and post a small self-contained GUI program that demonstrates your problem for us in a reproducible way.

Comment: okay, i'll try going to take a while.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I made a seperate small program without the model and it haves the proper GUI screen as desired. The model is extremely big itself, I don't think i can make a smaller version of it.

Comment: @NoobestPros, `I made a seperate small program without the model and it haves the proper GUI screen as desired` - so you have proved the basic logice works.  `I don't think i can make a smaller version of it.` - so then you need to debug your real application to see what is different. We can't guess what you are doing differently.

Comment: @camickr yeah im currently testing everything i can right now. Might provide update soon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels after several hours, i finally figured out the problem. I had a getX() and getY() method while extending JPanel. Which override the method and created the error. It works fine now once i removed it.

Comment: Good show -- that will do it, that will mess up the layouts.